# QStandardItemModel - how to ignore data changed event by row moved but NOT by cell changes from user

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QStandardItemModel with table view.

My table allows moving rows and for user to edit a cell.

I want to catch the cell changes from user edits.

Problem is, if a user drags a row, and/or edits cells the same signals are fired.  How can I grab the cell changes and ignore the row changes?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to Subclass the QStandarItemModel.  Don't waste time trying to track from the GUI by item selected, clicked, pressed.  Once you subclass, you're now in control of how the model (which is your data) is going to work, we can do anything.

In particular, look at ::itemData, the ::dropMimeData and ::setData functions.  Between those items you know which are from internal dnd or not.  You can store to var's, emit by Qt's sig/slot mechanism to GUI, or whatever your class needs.

Another useful tool is to hook into the deleget closeEditor func:

```
#include <QAbstractItemDelegate>
QAbstractItemDelegate * d = tv->itemDelegate();
 connect(d, &QAbstractItemDelegate::closeEditor, this, &MainWindow::endEditHint);
```

Hope this helps anyone who might have this arise.